# How to deal with buttons with Physic2D and Images (PNG)?

Tags: image, unity-game-engine, uibutton

I want to know how to create button with my Images(PNG). 
I'm not gonna use the GUIButton because of creating the default button image.

I copied the images in my Unity Project and changed to sprite(2D and UI). Then, create the sprites simply by dragging. I also added the script which includes 'onTouchDown() and onMouseDown'. However, it didn't work so I tired again with layermask but it didn't work as well with no error code. Maybe the physic2D is the reason.

How can i make button with simple image. Could you guys help me to do so?
Please let me know does anyone have idea. Thank you.

Comment: Please don't use unity tag got questions related to Unity game engine. There's unity3d tag for that.

Comment: #golergka sorry i didn't know that. Anyway thank you for letting me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry guys. I didn't recognize that i typed 'OnMouseDown' to 'onMouseDown'. I didn't used capital letter. It's really annoying thing.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use [a button from the new UI system](http://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/ui/ui-button)?